# Production and Development environment using Phing and SVN

Tags: php, svn, codeigniter, environment, phing

I have some questions about development and deployment. I'll try to be clear:

Notes:

1- I'm using Codeigniter for my project. I have in my database.php config file set up two environments: development and production with two different settings, of course.

2- I have two domains in the same server, one is for development (dev.domain.com) and the other one for production (domain.com)

3- The SVN repository is on the same server and it is under a subdomain too (svn.domain.com)

4- Locally, Im using MAMP server and I have a virtual Host for testing. Also, I'm using Netbeans and Git for managing the repo (git-svn commands)

5- I read the other similar posts, but I think my project have some differences to take into account

Questions:

I want to make changes locally and then, using Phing, deploy the changes to the development environment. This environment is just for testing purposes, I want to keep my production environment running, but if I add some new features, I want to test them in a real environment (server) before add them to the production environment.

1- What happens with the config files? If I deploy the development environment, the database config should change aswell. I can do this with Phing, but then I'll have changes on my working tree and I'll need to commit it first and change them again when working locally.

2- Should I work with branches for every release to production? I can do a git svn rebase on the development environment, but what happens with the production one?

I have kind of mess on my head about all of this. Can you clear my mind a little bit, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use 2 separate branches for DEV and PROD (or trunk+branch) with different configs and different deploy targets for Phing (per "branches")

Merge tested changes from DEV to PROD after debug, tag merged (and working) revisions in PROD tree without additional branching

PS - using both Git and SVN seems as excess solution for me

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, please let me take a look and I'll be back with a feedback.